# IBM Cloud - Blockchain platform | Problem creating MSP definition

Tags: websphere, ibm-cloud, ibm-blockchain

I was making this [IBM offitial tutorial](https://github.com/IBM/Create-BlockchainNetwork-IBPV20/blob/master/README.md) but i got stucked at step 4, "Create the peer organization MSP definition".

I cannot finish creating a Blockchain network using the IBM Blockchain Platform as I cannot select an administrator certificate enrollment ID and thus **create an MSP definition**, the dropdown menu does not appear.

[Link to a picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kUW2.png)

The description of the problem is in [this github issue](https://github.com/IBM/Create-BlockchainNetwork-IBPV20/issues/20) created by other user 14 days ago.

Comment: in your linked github issue the person describing the error described something they did that allowed them to get further - to another error - have you tried what they did and do you get to the same problem?

Comment: Hello and thanks for participating in the post, I was observing what the creator of the issue had done, but I preferred to focus on the root problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution by doing the tutorial in the [following link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAC0PPPFxLE), apparently there is an error using capitalization in the MSP ID when you are in the "Create the peer organization MSP definition" section.